# Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: amsgrad

Tags: python, keras

When trying to follow the [Keras doc](https://keras.io/optimizers/) on Adam, I copy this line from the doc:

```
keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
```

and get this error

> Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: amsgrad

---

**EDIT 1**

Omitting the `amsgrad` parameter agrees to interprt the line

`keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)`

but then when trying to train the model using

```
happyModel.fit(x = X_train, y = Y_train, epochs = 50, batch_size = 600)
```

gives the following error:

> None values not supported.

Full error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
> ----> 2 happyModel.fit(x = X_train, y = Y_train, epochs = 50, batch_size = 100)
> 3 ### END CODE HERE ###
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
> fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> **kwargs)    1574         else:    1575             ins = x + y + sample_weights
> -> 1576         self._make_train_function()    1577         f = self.train_function    1578
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
> _make_train_function(self)
> 958                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
> 959                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
> --> 960                         loss=self.total_loss)
> 961                 updates = self.updates + training_updates
> 962                 # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in
> wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + 86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
> ---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 88         wrapper._original_function = func
> 89         return wrapper
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py in
> get_updates(self, loss, params)
> 432             m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
> 433             v_t = (self.beta_2 * v) + (1. - self.beta_2) * K.square(g)
> --> 434             p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)
> 435
> 436             self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py
> in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
> 827       if not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
> 828         try:
> --> 829           y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
> 830         except TypeError:
> 831           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
> 674       name=name,
> 675       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
> --> 676       as_ref=False)
> 677
> 678
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref,
> preferred_dtype)
> 739
> 740         if ret is None:
> --> 741           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
> 742
> 743         if ret is NotImplemented:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py
> in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
> 111                                          as_ref=False):
> 112   _ = as_ref
> --> 113   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
> 114
> 115
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py
> in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
> 100   tensor_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue()
> 101   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
> --> 102       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
> 103   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
> 104   const_tensor = g.create_op(
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py
> in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
> 362   else:
> 363     if values is None:
> --> 364       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
> 365     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
> 366     # provided if possible.
>
> ValueError: None values not supported.

Thus, simply omitting the parameter doesn't do the trick.

How can I get the adam optimizer to work?

Comment: You need one of the latest versions of Keras for this to work, and you probably have an old version.

Comment: Indeed; omitting the `amsgrad` argument altogether will probably do the trick, too

Comment: @desertnaut editted the original question. what you suggest gives another error

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with Adam, but with your data... My suggestion worked in that it passed successfully the compilation part

Comment: You're getting this error because you have `None` values in your data (Y_train I think)

Comment: Solved. the error is because epsilon is None. (why wouldn't keras give a more informative error message is beyond me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is probably due to an old version of keras which does not support the `amsgrad` parameter
2. Removing the parameter allows the interpreter to understand the line.
3. The `None values not supported` problem comes from None in the `epsilon` parameter. You need to specify a value.

Answer (score 0):

epsilon is a small constant for numerical stability and None value is not supported by epsilon.
for epsilon Default value is 1e-7.
[source](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adam/)